# iOS : initWithCoder fail : 'Exercised class for selector implementation needs to be pushed'

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, initwithcoder

I have an UIImageView subclassed as CLImageView that has been implemented with lazy load.

Just ago I have encountered this **error message** :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Exercised class for selector implementation needs to be pushed'
*** First throw call stack:
```

**at line : if(self=[super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {**

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if(self=[super initWithCoder:aDecoder]){
        self.placeholderImage = nil;
        self.delegate = nil;
        self.cacheEnabled = NO;
        self.prettyLoad = NO;
    }return self;
}
```

I have never seen this error until 5 years of iOS programming, and I could not find any information on this kind of message here.

If anybody can drop me some ideas would be grateful.

If you need more information just leave a comment or reply.

Thank you so much.